# compare two vectors of string (character)

Tags: c++

I want to compare two vectors string

```
 vector <string> morse ={"A.-","B-...","C-.-.", "D-..", "E.", "F..-.", "G--.", "H....", "I.." ,"J.---", "K-.-", "L.-..", "M--" ,"N-." ,"O---" ,"P.--.", "Q--.-", "R.-.", "S...", "T-", "U..-", "V...-", "W.--" ,"X-..-" ,"Y-.--", "Z--.."};


vector<string> codeMorse (1);
codeMorse ={".---.--.-.-.-.---...-.---."};

     if (morse[i][j]==codeMorse[k]){    //my problem here =error


        }
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: IMHO I would not store the character with the morse code but instead use a `std::pair` and split them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems:

1. You can't make 2-Dimensional vector that way nor you even tried to make it 2D.
2. You wrote `morse[i][j]` without previous definition of i and j.

To fix issue 1 & 2:

Include

```
#include <vector>
```

Make a vector of std::pair(s):

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> morse;
```

That allows you to have a pair of strings.
To add a new morse code, use this:

```
morse.push_back(std::pair<std::string, std::string>("LETTER HERE", "MORSE CODE HERE"));
```

To read 'em use this:

```
//read all via loop
    for (int i = 0; i <= morse.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Letter: " << morse[i].first << std::endl;         //.first access your first elemt of the pair
        std::cout << "Morse Code: " << morse[i].second << std::endl;    //.second to access the morse code
    }
```

OR use iterators if you already know them:

```
//read all via loop
    for (auto i = morse.begin(); i != morse.end(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Letter: " << i->first << std::endl;           //->first access your first elemt of the pair
        std::cout << "Morse Code: " << i->second << std::endl;      //->second to access the morse code
    }
```

Of course you can read specific values:

```
std::cout << morse[0].first << std::endl;  //[] same use as the array's brackets
std::cout << morse[0].second << std::endl; //same here
```